# Circle theorems question I can't solve involving dodecagon...

Tags: geometry, circles

This is my last resort, as I can't figure it out at all!

https://www.drfrostmaths.com/getfile.php?fid=655

This worksheet was given to us (GCSE Maths, top set, yr 11, UK) about a month or two ago in a lesson on circle theorems. The question we all had trouble with was the second-from-bottom one on the second page, marked skull-and-cross-bones (b). Nobody, not even the teacher could solve it. The closest I got was by assuming that the non-circle shape was a regular dodecagon and therefore had interior angles of 150 degrees. Thus, I was able to conclude that the shape invloving the portion of the dodecagon inside the circle, as well as angle X, was a hexagon. I then worked out that a+b+x = 270 degrees, where a and b are the angles at those points between the lines of the dodecagon inside the circle and the line linking to angle x. However, I was not able to work out any more! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's **a** which is marked skull and cross bones. Do you mean **a** or **b**?

Comment: @Bernard All the questions a,b,c on page two are implicitly marked skull and crossbones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Draw lines from $A$ and $B$ to the circle centre $O$. This encloses a hexagon to the left of the newly drawn lines; its internal angles must sum to $720^\circ$. Three of those angles are internal angles of the dodecagon, hence $150^\circ$ each; two more are at $A$ and $B$ and are $60^\circ$ each – $150^\circ$ minus the right angle that appears because the new lines are circle radii. This leaves the last angle as $150^\circ$. As this is the angle subtended by a chord from the centre, the angle subtended at any point at the edge – the desired $x$ – is half that, $75^\circ$.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I knew it had to be something to do with one of the circle theorems but completely missed that you could join radii from the circle's centre to the circumference and that they'd be perpendicular to a side of the dodecagon. In hindsight, it seems quite obvious! Thanks again, made my day to finally have a solution.